# How to call createFormContent() method in FormPage class when using eclipse WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder, multipage

How to call createFormContent() method in the class(extended by FormPage class) which is created by eclipse WindowBuilder plugin? I created a class to act as a swt gui using eclipse window Buider plugin, but I am unable to use it in my java class which is actually a multi page editor. I want to use that UI in a page in my multi page editor. How to do that? I think I should call that createFormContent(IManagedForm managedForm) method but what should be passed as the argument?

Answer (score 0):

Your editor should extend `FormEditor`.

In the `addPages` method of `FormEditor` you add your `FormPage` pages by calling the `addPage(IFormPage)` method.

Provided you have done the above the page `createFormContent` will be called automatically when the editor is created.